# Laser cooling of a trapped ion

Tags: atomic-physics, laser, cooling

I have Ca+ ion trapped at $z = 0$ in a harmonic trap. According to C. Foot's "Atomic Physics" the force on ion can be expressed as:
$$
F=-\kappa(z-z_0)-\alpha v,
$$
when it's cooled from one direction with laser beam with intensity I and detuning $\delta$. The laser excites a transition where the excited state has the
some spontaneous emission rate $\Gamma$. The $z_0$ in this case is $\hbar k \Gamma/4\kappa$.

I am wondering where this equation comes from. I started with general expression for force:
$$
F=\hbar k \frac{\Gamma}{2}\frac{I/I_{sat}}{1+I/I_{sat}+4 \delta^2/\Gamma^2},
$$
but I don't know how to insert the velocity of ion into this eqution.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in a harmonic trap, then by definition the potential term is of the form:
$$ V(z) = \frac{1}{2}\kappa (z-z_0)^2, $$
which means the force will be:
$$ F_z = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial z} = -\kappa(z-z_0), $$
and that's the first term.

For the second term, you start from the scattering force $F$ that you quote. The $k = \omega/c$ and $\delta = \omega - \omega_0$ in the expression  both depend on the laser frequency seen by the atom/ion $\omega$, where $\omega_0$ is the separation of its energy levels.

A moving ion at speed $v$ will see a Doppler shifted laser frequency $\omega \rightarrow \omega \pm  kv$ (sign depending on direction of laser beam). This is how the velocity of the atom comes in.

Usually, laser cooling works with two counter propagating beams, i.e. going along the $+$ and $-$ directions along a single axis. In this case, an ion moving at speed $v$ experiences the following *net* force:
$$ F[(\omega - kv) - \omega_0)] - F[(\omega + kv) - \omega_0] \approx -2\frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega}kv = -\alpha v, $$
where the $\approx$ is the result of a Taylor expansion in $v$.